# Handle JQuery remove event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

So I have a custom loading animation that uses modality to block the UI. I'm also using jquery dialog boxes to inform the user for confirmations or certain events.

The problem i'm having is that I need to do an ajax request right after they click a "Confirm" button on the jquery dialog box, which whenever I do any ajax requests I start the loading animation. However, when I destroy and remove the dialog box and run the ajax request, the event bubbling is happening in a way that is messing things up. Even if I have .dialog("destroy").remove() before the submission of the transaction it does the destroy and remove AFTER the transaction code happens. When it does that it removes all modality I have on the screen, essentially turning off my loading animation and allowing the user to do whatever they want.

I put in a timer which works, but I don't like handling this with a timer. I was wondering if there's any other way to handle this?

Let me also add that I'm supporting ie8 with this.

The code is kind of irrelevant because the underlying issue is that doing the destroy and remove seems to be put at the bottom of the event queue, but here's the gist:

```
var elem = $("#" + ctx.id);
var button = $("#btn-confirm");
button.bind("click", function() {
     elem.dialog("destroy").remove();
     validateEntry = ValidateEntry.getInstance();
     validateEntry.callback = new ValidateEntryHandler(this.content);
     validateEntry.submit();
}
```

....

```
// There is inheritance for the transaction class for each service.
submit = function() {
app.loadAnim.start();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: this.getApi_path(),
        data: req, 
        contentType: 'application/xml; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "xml",
        async: ctx.async,
        timeout: ctx.getService_timeout(),
        success: function(xml)
        {
            if(typeof ctx.returnXML === "undefined"){
                 ctx.submitHandler(req, JsonixUtil.jsonixUnmarshaller(xml, ctx.jsonixKey));
            }
            else{
                ctx.submitHandler(req, xml);
            }        
        },
        error: function(response, strError)
        {
            ctx.callback.onFailure(response);
        }
    });
}
```

....

```
//Load animation start code
start: function(dotDelay, textDelay){
    //set array of images         
    var ss = $('.sliding-dots').children('img');         
    var ssize = ss.size();
    var anim = this;
    if(!this.isShowing){
        this.isShowing = true;
        this.dotTimer = setInterval(function() {                
        for(var i = 0; i < anim.dots.length; i++){
            anim.alpha = 1 - Math.abs(anim.currImg-i)*.25;
            anim.alpha = (anim.alpha > 0) ? anim.alpha : 0;
                $(ss[i]).css('opacity',anim.alpha);
            }
        anim.currImg = (anim.currImg == anim.dots.length-1) ? 0 : anim.currImg+1;
    }, this.dotDelay);
    $('.load-animation').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.load-animation .text-body').css({opacity: 0}).delay(this.textDelay).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
```

}

Comment: Share your code, please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the destroy/remove in a callback when your ajax call returns.  For example

```
$.ajax('/some/url')
    .done(function(response){
        $dialog.dialog('destroy').remove();
    });
```

Comment: This would remove consistency from the app as most popups close and then the load animation happens.Also there's another service call directly after that service call so the same thing would happen again.